# Magento 2 Rest API - PUT method always return "Class ... does not exist"

Tags: api, rest, magento, magento2

- I have created magento 2 rest api endpoint for PUT request and it always returns "**Class .. does not exist**".
- There are 2 param's in PUT request:
- path parameter: id, json string in body of PUT request: data

ExampleInterface:

```
    /**
 * @param int $id
 * @param mixed $data
 * @return string
 */
public function create($id, $data);
```

Model:

```
    public function create($id, $data) {...}
```

webapi.xml:

```
    <route url=".../:id/create" method="PUT">
      <service class=".../ExampleInterface" method="create"/>
      <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
      </resources>
    </route>
```

Inerface and model are connected and everything is fine. **I have same endpoint like that one which receives same parameters but POST method is used and it works fine**. When I change it to PUT then always second parameter is causing problems even though everything in interface and method is correct and same.

**Important:** If I remove one of these two parameters(path parameter or the one in body of PUT request), then it works fine. But when there is a combination of path parameter and json string in body, then always second one is causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it likes the '@param mixed $data'.

try '@param string[] $data' or '@param mixed[] $data'